# How to import jsPDF v2 in Angular 7

Tags: angular, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF in Angular 7 project.
I was on jsPDF v1.3.5 and used `import *  as jsPDF from 'jspdf';` to import.

Now I upgraded to v2.0.0 and after the upgrade, I tried these imports with the respective errors

```
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf"); //Cannot find name 'jsPDF'.
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';     // Error:Property 'setFontType' does not exist on type 'jsPDF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use this to import jsPDF

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
```

if you check the [change log](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases) on github, you will see that setFontType was removed from version 2

- `Removed APIs that were previously marked as deprecated. Namely: addHTML, fromHTML, html2pdf, addSvg, addButton, addTextField, addChoiceField, cellInitialize, setFontStyle, setFontType, clip_fixed.`

Comment: it shows this warning: `WARNING in ./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js 195:240-254
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
`

Comment: perhaps you imported the script twice? in the angular.json and using the import statements

Comment: if the code works , you should just ignore it for now, source: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2846